# parse xml and save data

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, sqlite

I've a question and couldn't really find a direct answer to this.

I have an app which downloads all its content from xml files. Unfortunately, when the user doesn't have an internet connection the App is useless. I want my app to be usefull also when there is no internet.

What I want to do now is check if there is internet, and if so, download and parse the xml and retrieve all the images and text. Next, I want to save this and only on request from the user, refresh the data. If there is no internet, the app should go straight to its saved xml file and its saved images etc.

I need to know how to save images and text, and is this even allowed? I read somewhere how to save images to the document folder, but I can say that there will be around 300 images, is this not going to be a big mess? Is this even allowed?

Further, how can I save text? Is it possible to do this with a combination of sqlite and saving to documents folder?

Prastow

Answer (score 0):

you can store content in plist instead of xml

**set value into plist**

```
 NSData * data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:YourDataArray];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *Path =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.plist",docDir,@"Content"];
    NSLog(@"%@",Path);
    BOOL didWriteSuccessfull = [data writeToFile:Path atomically:YES];
    if (didWriteSuccessfull) {
        NSLog(@"store succsessfully");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"no");
    }
```

**get value from plist**

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *Path =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.plist",docDir,@"Content"];


if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:Path])
{

    NewsToDisplay=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:Path]]];

}
```

Comment: But this only works with strings right? Plist doesn't has values for uiimage, or is it possible that the value for each image is also a string; the location of the local iphone folder?

Comment: but how can u store image in xml ya u can store image url in xml and than can happen in plist also.

Comment: yes but i want to save the actual image, not only the image url, the image should be able to view without internet

Comment: than you have to cache the images or you can store in db with blob datatype.